# Toggle Class on Element on Focus and Tab Key Pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am currently trying to toggle the a class when the info icon is both focused when the tab key is pressed. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/carlosNavient/pen/OzjvEG) of my current work.

HTML:

```
 <i class="fa fa-info-circle" id="disclaimerTooltip" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="myfield_description"></i> 

<span class="test myfield_description" role="tooltip">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
 </span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#disclaimerTooltip')
  .bind('focus keypress', function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  console.log(keyCode);
  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    $('.test').toggleClass('myfield_description')
  } 

})
```

When I tab into the info icon, I get the keycode of 0 insted of 9.

Comment: Add `console.log(e.type)` to see whether you're seeing a trigger of `focus` or of `keypress`.

Comment: Focusing on the icon and then tabbing off of it seems to give keycode 9

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJdVoZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with css and not js - and I'd argue it's better in many cases though I don't know yours in particular.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJdxEW

css

```
.myfield_description {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

i:focus .myfield_description,
i:hover  .myfield_description {
  position: static;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

html

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" id="disclaimerTooltip" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="myfield_description">
  <span class="test myfield_description" role="tooltip">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </span>
</i>
```

Comment: How does this check if tabbing caused the `:focus`?

Comment: It doesn't. Perhaps it doesn't need to. I don't know what "trying to toggle the a class when the info icon is both focused when the tab key is pressed" means, and op hasn't responded to any comments.